# Is it possible to create a data exchange and share it with reader accounts?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know both serve similar kinds of use case, but I was wondering if this is possible or if anyone has tried it, because instead of managing individual reader accounts I can just manage the data exchange. Does reader accounts have access to snowflake's data exchange service?

Comment: They do have access to browse the Data Exchange, but getting data from it is another question. I believe Reader accounts can only consume data shared from its parent account and I am not sure if that includes a listing the parent account would make.  You can certainly test it if you'd already a provider on the Data Exchange.  Otherwise, I'd recommend reaching out to your Snowflake Account Team or Sales Engineers with your use cases so they can offer suggestions about current or upcoming features to facilitate.

Comment: Thank you! Reader accounts are listed in the documentation under direct share but wasn't mentioned at all under data exchange hence the question, but I'll reach out to snowflake support to see if this is possible.